# Changing Columns 22-300 from double (or other type) into numeric

Tags: r, types, numeric, column-types

I have a huge dataset and some columns are text. Upon importing the Excel file and using preview, I can manually change the first 50 columns to numeric, if this applies. But, there are still 250 more columns I need to change to numeric. How would I use R code to change all columns from column 22 through column 300 to numeric?

Comment: If you want to convert all columns of one type into another, you can use `mutate_if()`. For example, here's the code to convert all character columns to numeric: `mutate_if(dataframe, is.character, as.numeric)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
mydf[22:300] <- lapply(mydf[22:300], as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `type.convert` (assuming the columns are `character` class)

```
df1[22:300] <- type.convert(df1[22:300], as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Also, with `mutate_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     mutate_at(22:300, type_convert)
```